# Когда я пытаюсь установить на ImageView изображение с помощью указания пути, оно исчезает. В чем дело?

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

Я пытаюсь выбранное из галереи изображение установить в ImageView, и чтобы при запуске этой активити изображение которое я выбрал устанавливалась туда же автоматически. Но когда я запускаю активити, ImageView исчезает, и фотка которую я тогда выбирал не появляется вообще. В чем причина скажите пожалуйста! Заранее Спасибо!

```
public SharedPreferences savedImageSharedPreferens;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about_me);
        Window w = getWindow();
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        savedImageSharedPreferens = getSharedPreferences("savedImage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String saved = savedImageSharedPreferens.getString("path", "");
        ImageView userPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userPhoto);
        userPhoto.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File(saved)));
    }

public void EditBtn(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), GALLERY_REQUEST);
    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userPhoto);
        switch(requestCode) {
            case GALLERY_REQUEST:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    Picasso.with(AboutMe.this).load(selectedImage).transform(new CircularTransformation(150)).noPlaceholder().centerCrop().fit()
                            .into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userPhoto));

                    savedImageSharedPreferens = getSharedPreferences("savedImage", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    String pathData = selectedImage.toString();
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editorSavedImage = savedImageSharedPreferens.edit();
                    editorSavedImage.putString("path", pathData).apply();
                }
        }
    }
```

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/userPhoto"
        android:layout_width="122dp"
        android:layout_height="121dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/user_photo_blue_about_me"
        android:onClick="EditBtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.487"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/userphoto" />
```

Comment: причина в неправильном методе выборе изображения, эта тема разжевана на англоязычном форуме

Comment: Можете меня направить? А то я уже несколько дней на это потратил. Или может быть у вас есть код с объяснением

Comment: [вперед](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider?hl=ru)

Comment: Если хотите проще используйте Intent.ACTION_PICK